# Using JavaScript map methods within a React file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, jsx

I am writting this code inside a JSX file.

I am trying to loop through an array of objects and render some of its elements in the browser using React JSX. I am also using a conditional statement. My code is as follow :

```
const Users = [
   {
       firstName: 'Peter',
       lastName: 'Parker',
       age: 17
   },
   {
       firstName: 'Bruce',
       lastName: 'Wayne',
       age: 35
   }    
];

const FormatName = (user) => {
    return user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName
}

const Greetings = (users) => {
    users.map((person) => {
        if (person.age >= 18) {
            return <h1>{FormatName(person)}is an adult</h1>
        }
        return <h1>{FormatName(person)} is a minor</h1>
    })
    
}

ReactDOM.render(
    Greetings(Users),
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

My issue is within the Greeting function. If I write a console.log, I can see that my object is being read but for some reason I can't add it to the DOM.

If someone could give me a hand, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your question title should be: Adding element to the DOM using map() function

Comment: You forgot the `return` statement in `Greetings`.

Answer (score 1):

Change `Greetings` component to:

```
const Greetings = (users) => {
    return(users.map((person) => {
        if (person.age >= 18) {
            return <h1>{FormatName(person)}is an adult</h1>
        }
        return <h1>{FormatName(person)} is a minor</h1>
    }));
    
}
```

and  `ReactDOM.render` to:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Greetings users={users} />,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Comment: Hey Medi! Thanks a lot for your answer. For some reasons, the Greetings functions didn't render with the argument (users). I had to do as follow : 

const Greetings = () => {
    return(users.map((person) => {
        if (person.age >= 18) {
            return <h1>{FormatName(person)}is an adult</h1>
        }
        return <h1>{FormatName(person)} is a minor</h1>
    }));
}